# Plpgsql: How can i delete a specific row from view by passing the value from function?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to delete a row from view by passing the value from function but getting an error the column `rollno` does not exist.

For example:

Table

```
create table tbl1  
( rollnumber int,  
name varchar);
```

Inserting some rows

```
insert into tbl1 values(1,'abc');  
insert into tbl1 values(2,'def');  
insert into tbl1 values(3,'ghi');
```

View

```
create view view1 as select * from tbl1;
```

Deleting a specific row from view1 from my function.

```
create or replace function function1(rollno int)  
returns void as  
$body$  
declare  
        temp varchar;  
begin  
        temp:='delete from view1 where rollnumber=rollno';  
        execute temp;  
end;  
$body$  
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
    temp:='delete from view1 where rollnumber=rollno';
```

cannot possibly work. You're not substituting a variable, you're literally running that query as written.

I think you might have meant:

```
    temp:='delete from view1 where rollnumber = ' || quote_literal(rollno);
    execute temp;
```

which is better written as a parameterized query:

```
EXECUTE 'delete from view1 where rollnumber = $1' USING rollno;
```

but in this case, there's not any need to make it dynamic SQL at all, so you can just write:

```
create or replace function function1(rollno int)  
returns void as $$
delete from view1 where rollnumber=$1;
$$
language SQL;
```